# List comprehension to replace the first n items in array with 0

Tags: python, numba

I'm writing a jitted function to replace the first N elements in a multi-dimensional array with 0. I will be doing this many, many times so speed is important. @njit speeds it up significantly but I'm wondering if there is a way to get rid of the for loop using list comprehension. Would that help improve the efficiency of this? Any suggestions?

```
 import numpy as np
 from numba import njit

 lengths=np.random.randint(0,365, size=20)

 @njit
 def availarray(lengths):
     out=1+np.zeros((365, len(lengths)))
     for i in range(int(len(lengths))):
         out[:int(lengths[i]), i]=0*int(lengths[i])
     return out
```

Comment: For starters, `0*int(lengths[i])` is the same as `0`. Also, list comprehension almost never performs better than a vanilla `for` loop, and is quite useless in your case since you do not have lists.

Comment: All conversions to `int()` can be removed. Finally, `np.ones((365, len(lengths)))` is better than `1+np.zeros((365, len(lengths)))`.

Comment: First thought, `out = np.ones((365, len(lengths))` instead of `1 + np.zeros(...)` shaves off a couple of microseconds on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize: get rid of all calls to `int` and `len`; get rid of multiplication by 0; generate the original array efficiently.

```
def availarray(lengths):
    out = np.ones((365, lengths.size))
    for i in range(lengths.size):
        out[:lengths[i], i] = 0
    return out
```

This shrinks the execution time from 49 mks to 31.7 mks.

Starting with an array of zeros and stuffing it with 1s works even better:

```
def availarray(lengths):
    out = np.zeros((365, lengths.size))
    for i in range(lengths.size):
        out[lengths[i]:, i] = 1
    return out
```

In my case, this further reduces the execution time to 26.3 mks, a 46% speedup.

Answer (score 0):

I got the run time down by about 30% using:

```
def avail_array(lengths):
    out = np.zeros((365, len(lengths)))
    for i in range(int(len(lengths))):
        out[int(lengths[i]):, i] = 1
    return out
```

- Your version:

  > 41 µs ± 734 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- This version:

  > 28.2 µs ± 353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

This may just be a quirk of what random lengths were selected, but at the very least not using `0*len(lengths[i])` and either using `np.ones(...)` or `np.zeros(...)` and not `1 + np.zeros(...)` is a good start.